# How to connect some number of points of the map with a line?

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet, openstreetmap

I need to connect some number of points on osm map. I'm using leaflet routing machine right now but it doesn't connect points if one of them lies not on the road. I mean this:

[image: As you can see it doesn't completely connect two last points]

As you can see it doesn't completely connect two last points.

Can anyone tell me please how can I manage to do this? Maybe there is some libs or something else?

Comment: Try creating a simple line from the start/end of the generated route to your start/end points.

Comment: @scai that's won't help. On this img of a map there are three points that aren't connected( two of them are without a marker). So may be there is another way to do this?